Mean curvature as a contraction
I'm going over some of Kobayashi's work on complex vector bundles and trying to state some of the notions in a more familiar language to me.
The set up is the following. We have a hermitian vector bundle $(E,h)$ of rank $r$ over a complex $n$-dimensional manifold $X$ and the unique hermitian connection $\nabla$.
If in addition $X$ is equipped with a hermitian metric $g$ with $$g=\sum g_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}dz^\alpha\otimes d\bar{z}^\beta$$ we denote the inverse matrix of $g$ with $(g^{\alpha\bar{\beta}})$. Now comes the two notions I'm trying to translate. Kobayashi defines something called the mean curvature transformation and mean curvature form.

Let  $$K^i_j=\sum g^{\alpha\bar{\beta}}R^i_{j\alpha\bar{\beta}}, \quad K_{j\bar{k}}= \sum h_{i\bar{k}}K^i_j.$$ Then $K=(K^i_j)$ defines an endomorphism of $E$ and $\hat{K}=(K_{j\bar{k}})$ defines the corresponding hermitian form in $E$ by $$K(\xi)=\sum K^i_j\xi^js_i, \quad \hat{K}(\xi,\eta)=\sum K_{i\bar{k}}\xi^j\bar{\eta}^k$$ for $\xi=\sum\xi^is_i$ and $\eta = \sum \eta^is_i$. Here $(s_1,\dots,s_r)$ is a local frame.

Now to me these look like some kinds of contractions of the curvature tensor $R$ provided by $\nabla$, but I can't get my mind around on what these are. If anyone here could provide me some insights on how to view these as contractions and what is the difference between $K$ and $\hat{K}$, I would be very grateful. I'm coming from a Riemannian geometry background and I'm familiar with contractions of $R$ such as the Ricci contraction, but this is quite new to me. These things seem to "live" on different spaces somehow as the former uses $g$ which is a metric on the manifold or more specifically on the tangent bundle of $X$ and $\hat{K}$ involves $h$ which is a metric on the bundle $E$.
